# Express - Getting proxy error when trying to insert record to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mongodb-native

I want to insert a record into my mongoDB collection, then retrieve it. Using express.js

```
exports.index = function(req,res){

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, db) {

        var coll = db.collection('kittens');

        var obj = {
            foo: 'bar'
        };

        coll.insert(obj);

        coll.find({}, function(err, docs) {
          res.json(docs);
        });

    });

};
```

The server responds with `502 Proxy Error`

> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /*urlhere*/.
>   Reason: Error reading from remote server

If i omitt the `insert()`, the server will respind with an empty object.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: seems like there is a proxy between your js and mongodb. are they on different servers?

Comment: nope, it's the same server

Comment: can you provide apache error log?

Comment: Besides the proxy problem: You have to call `call.find()` within the callback of `coll.insert()`. If you are unlucky mongo executes your find at first and you will not get your docs, because they are yet not inserted.